# Working in separate prefix in Linux

Tags: linux, environment-variables, apt-get

I'm downloading on open source Linux tool and trying to build it.

The build guide says that I need to work in a separate prefix to avoid corrupting the system. For that I have created a my_prefix dir and written a setup-env file in it, its as follows : setup-env

```
    PROJECT=~/my_prefix
    export PATH=$PROJECT/install/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PROJECT/install/lib:$PATH
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PROJECT/install/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
    export AC_LOCAL_FLAGS="-I $PROJECT/install/share/aclocal $ACLOCAL_FLAG"
```

After this I do source setup-env

Now whenever I install a new tool using, sudo apt-get install, it should go into my new install dir, but its getting updated in /usr/bin only.

Any idea what could be the reason?